# Using pyunpack.Archive on Cloud Run with rar file results in empty result

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, rar

I've been using `pyunpack.Archive().extractall(tempdir)` successfully in a Cloud Run instance to extract `.tar.gz` and `.zip` files to a `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`, but when I try the same approach with `.rar` files, I just get an empty temporary directory.

The strange thing is that the code works when run locally (On Ubuntu 20.04).

I have been wondering whether it has something to do with the system installation of the linux `rar`/ `unrar` binaries. I only managed to intall `unrar-free` using Docker. When trying to install `unrar` or `rar`, I get "No installation candidate" errors, despite adding the Multiverse ppa.

There is no error output when extracting the rar file, it just doesn't result in any output. I have checked the integrity of the rar file as well.

Comment: Do you see any syscall issues in the application logs on Cloud Console?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google, no there are no warnings or errors in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED it by adding the non-free repositories and installing both unrar and unrar-free

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
apt-get update && \
#apt-get install -y python-software-properties && \
#apt-get update && \
apt-add-repository non-free

RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
        unrar-free \
        unrar
```